# Is there a method to apply kind of trinary operator on mysql query?

Tags: mysql

is there possible to do something like this in mysql:
`SELECT foo, bar, (created_at > '2012-12-12' ? 'actual': 'old') FROM table;`, is there a function that allows me to do this?

Comment: Either [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) (standard SQL) or [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) (MySQL specific) should do it.

Comment: The ANSI standard method is `case`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IF` is a (slightly) more verbose way of doing what you want:

```
SELECT foo, bar, IF(created_at > '2012-12-12','actual','old') FROM table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) which is MySQL specific;

```sql
SELECT foo, bar, IF(created_at > '2012-12-12', 'actual', 'old') 
FROM table1
```

[(SQLFiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54ae/1)

...or you can use [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) which is ANSI standard and works across pretty much any SQL dialect (Oracle/SQL Server/PostgreSQL/...)

```
SELECT foo, bar, CASE WHEN created_at > '2012-12-12'
                      THEN 'actual' 
                      ELSE 'old' 
                 END 
FROM table1
```

[(SQLfiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d54ae/2)